# Is there a good open source domain extractor?

Tags: url

My goal is to go from http://www.thing.com to thing.com. Or go from http://this.is.a.place.com.jp/ to place.com.jp. And so on. Is there an open source project that does this? I know that apache commons's URI has getHost, but that's not quite the same thing.

Edit: the purpose of this is not for a web server. It is for analytics and whatnot, when you have a bunch of different url's in a log, and you want to associate them with a domain. Sorry for the vague language.

Comment: You haven't said how you want to do this.  In a text editor?  On a web page?

Comment: In java, python, ruby, anything.

Comment: If you are still interested, I have one.

Answer (score 0):

You mean redirection?

Web server settings can deal with it. Normally, you may want site with `www` and without `www` be the same site. Therefore, you should forward one site to another with status `301 Moved Permanently`.

Comment: Shivan, thanks for the response. I edited my question to be less vague. What I actually want to be able to do is get the domain associated with the many url's that pop up in logs. IE for www.yahoo.com.br, mail.yahoo.com.br/a/page, a.thing.yahoo.com.br/page, I'd want to pull out "yahoo.com.br" for each of these.

Comment: I would like to clarify further. Which logs are you interested in? In what format? Your final output should be on screen or saved in database?

Comment: Imagine that I have a flat file with the following: www.yahoo.com.br\nmail.yahoo.com.br/a/page\na.thing.yahoo.com.br/page. I want a function which takes in each row, and would, in this case, output "yahoo.com."